# Reset IIS after CPU usage Hit 100

Tags: iis, performance-testing, w3wp

Currently I have an issue in which w3wp.exe locks the CPU at 100%. I need to solve this issue, but in the mean time, i would like to trigger an IIS reset when the CPU remains above 95% for more than 2 minutes.

I have been playing with performance monitor, but i need something which will allow for a time condition. (It may allow you to do this, but so far i haven't worked it out)

Any ideas to get this to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which OS system you are running on this will be more or less complicated.

You should be collecting thread dumps and OS statistics on the process broken down by threads inside that process.

Try a thread dump every second for about 10 to 20 iterations when CPU is maxed, you should be able to identify which thread is making your host cpu bound.

Of course you have to work on the specifics of getting this information depending on your OS and IIS.